# How do companies like Blizzard make diablo for both Mac and PC?

Tags: cross-platform

Mac programs are written in Objective-C.  PC programs are written in C# or vb.net.

So does Blizzard just make two programs?

Do they implement their core logic in some common language like C++?

What exactly do they do?

Comment: I cannot comment on what Blizzard might do, but your understanding or what Mac and PC programs use is incorrect. There are some languages that you can write with that will run on either platform - the main one being Java of which there are many programs out there written with. There are still a lot of programs being written for PCs in Visual Basic 6 and Visual C++.

Comment: You can't write programs in visual basic for mac. Even if you can apple will not allow distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mac programs are written in Objective-C. PC programs are written in C# or vb.net.

that statement seems to be the route of your misunderstanding, most platforms aren't bound to specific languages, however, some languages are easier to work with across platforms that others.

When it comes it blizzard, I know they have used Qt to write their launchers, making them cross platform. the games themselves on the other hand depend, older games where written in a combination on languages (C, C++ and x86 assembly), but these days it seems to be mostly C++ (note: this is from lots of RCE on their binaries, not from any official statements or anything).

That being said, the games aren't really *that* cross platform compatible, due to use of differing graphics API's (DirectX vs OpenGL) plus differing OS functions.

Comment: Programming in C++ is extremely difficult. You need standard library. On top of that you will need your own library for garbage collection, making sure things are neat.

Comment: @JimThio: you don't need garbage collection (smart pointers will do that for you), though most AAA engines have custom memory allocators, to manage the memory pattern and prevent stalls etc (however, these days, on can just drop in tcmalloc or nedmalloc, D3 used tcmalloc). most companies ALSO have internal standard libs (like EA's EASTL), which are then supplemented with things boost. And as with anything, it becomes easier the more you understand it.

Comment: I know about smart pointer. No 2 pointers can point to the same object for example. Also C++ doesn't support lambda expression yet and doing it C++ way using that overloaded :: operator (I think?) is VERY awkward.

Comment: @JimThio: AAA is jargon for big budget commercial games (and a little more but thats the jist). C++11 introduced lambda's, but my reference to smart pointers was for automatic memory management (they remove a lot of the need for garbage collectors)